How does the Trans component determine which translation function to use?
Setup:
I have a server side useLocales() function that returns a t function and my i18next instance as such:
import resourcesToBackend from "i18next-resources-to-backend"
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next/initReactI18next"

import { defaultResources } from "./constants"
import { determineLanguage, getOptions } from "./settings"
import { Language } from "./useLocales"

type ResourcesProp = {
  resources?: Record<string, any>
  selectedLanguage?: Language
}

async function setupServerI18n({
  resources = { ...defaultResources },
}: ResourcesProp = {}) {
  const lng = determineLanguage()

  const i18nInstance = createInstance()
  await i18nInstance
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(
      resourcesToBackend(
        (language: string, namespace: string) =>
          import(`./langs/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
      )
    )
    .init({
      ...getOptions(lng),
      resources,
    })

  return i18nInstance
}

export async function useLocales({
  resources = defaultResources,
  selectedLanguage,
}: ResourcesProp = {}) {
  const i18nextInstance = await setupServerI18n({ resources })
  const language = selectedLanguage ?? determineLanguage()
  i18nextInstance.changeLanguage(language)

  return {
    t: i18nextInstance.getFixedT(language),
    i18n: i18nextInstance,
  }
}

export const getLocales = useLocales

I have a server component called Footer which gets the selectedLanguage as a prop from a layout file. (layout is nested under [lang] folder and can use params to access locale). In this footer component I get the locale and i18next instance as such
const { t, i18n } = await getLocales({ selectedLanguage })

And then try to translate the following copy:
<p className="mt-2 leading-7">
   {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-undef */}
    <Trans
      i18nKey="layouts.footer.slogan"
      components={{ br: <br /> }}
      lang={selectedLanguage}
     />
     {t("layouts.footer.slogan")}
</p>

Translations using the t function translate perfectly, but Trans component uses the opposite locale somehow. I also can't pass the t function to the Trans component because I get the following error: Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".

try this one and don't forget to upvote me if it works
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78273131/19026350
